# Why do we need to use fixed before using setprecision(int n)?

Tags: c++

I was trying to set the precision to 6 digits but using `setprecision(6)` alone doesn't do the trick. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float num = 1.423;
    cout<<setprecision(6)<<num;
    return 0;
}
```

It results in `1.423` only rather then `1.423000` until I use `fixed`

```
cout<<setprecision(6)<<num;
```

Comment: There's no use of `fixed` in the code you show...

Comment: Use `std::fixed` if you want the output to be in *fixed format* mode.

Comment: @Eljay but why we need to set it to fixed?

Comment: You need to use [std::fixed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) because you want a behavior other than the default.

Comment: Set it to `std::fixed` to get fixed formatting.  Set it to `std::defaultfloat` to get the default formatting.

Comment: Because `1.423` is an "exact" representation for that float, `1.423000` adds nothing in terms of significant digits. `std::fixed` will keep the number of decimal places consistent, but `1.423` is "precise" to 6 decimals places already (0s are assumed, in essence). I believe most floats/doubles won't change their representation when set from a literal (so `1.423` will stay that way, it won't become the IEEE-754 value), but I'm uncertain how it is kept that way (perhaps via a static memory reference?).

Comment: @Eljay so `defaultfloat` ignores the `setprecision()` settings?

Comment: No, [`setprecision()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) has different behavior for `defaultfloat`.  View the code in the link.  Change the value of `pi` by adding `100'000.0L` to it, and see how that affects the output.

Answer (score -2):

That's because the num (1.423) has three non-zero digits after the decimal point. Thus, it will be displayed with three decimals, trailing zeros will be skipped. This is how it is designed to work.
Check these links for more information

https://cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

Comment: `1.423f` precision is not 3 in a `float`.  `float` precision is fixed based on the IEEE 754 32 bit specification.

Comment: I meant to say that it has only three non-zero digits.

Comment: No, 1.423f is actually 1.42299997806549072265625 (from https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)